# Usare 'presso il' e 'al' correttamente

Tags: word-choice

Leggendo questo stralcio di un [articolo](http://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adozionismo) scritto in Wikipedia,

> L'*Adozionismo* è la dottrina cristologica che fa di Gesù una creatura speciale, chiamata da Dio a una missione particolare, ma che resta su un piano inferiore rispetto al Creatore. Viene adottato dal Padre al momento del suo battesimo *al* fiume Giordano, momento in cui viene elevato al rango di Figlio di Dio, acquisendo così la natura divina.

mi sono chiesto se *al* in '... al momento del suo battesimo *al* fiume Giordano' sia accettabile, o se, invece, non si sarebbe dovuto scrivere *presso il*?

Se non è così, quando *presso il* e *al* non sono reciprocamente fungibili?

Cioè, come mai sembra corretto dire *il Vaticano ha chiesto di intercedere* ***presso il*** *governo cubano per far cessare la violenza*, ma non *il Vaticano ha chiesto di intercedere* ***al*** *governo cubano per far cessare la violenza*?

Comment: Folks, questa e' una domanda da vero greco!

Comment: Il battesimo non è stato “presso il fiume”, ma “dentro”. Non vedo nulla di strano in alcuno degli esempi. Nel secondo, il Vaticano non ha chiesto niente al governo cubano.

Comment: @egreg, non so, dire 'dentro', anche se effettivamente il battesimo è avvenuto 'dentro' il fiume, mi sembrerebbe strano. If any, userei 'nel' oppure 'sul', ma 'nel' potrebbe implicare che i soggetti coinvolti fossero completamente immersi nel fiume e dire 'sul', miracoli a parte, farebbe pensare a individui capaci di camminare sull'acqua. Comunque 'presso il' non esclude, in my opinion, che quelli fossero 'dentro' il fiume.

Comment: ... pensa, per esempio, a 'Procura della Repubblica *presso il* Tribunale di Velletri'. Qui è chiaro che gli uffici della Procura sono proprio 'dentro' il Tribunale, credo.

Comment: ... e poi, se proprio '**il Vaticano ha chiesto di intercedere al governo cubano per far cessare la violenza**' implicasse realmente la descrizione di una richiesta, forse sarebbe meglio dire '**il Vaticano ha chiesto al governo cubano di intercedere per far cessare la violenza**' postponendo 'di intercedere' a 'al governo cubano', credo.

Comment: Non c'entra nulla. Non si parla degli uffici, ma dell'istituzione “Procura della Repubblica” che è associata al Tribunale. Quanto al Vaticano, ripeto che quella frase implica che il Vaticano non si è per nulla rivolto al governo cubano.

Comment: @martina, so che con gli accenti sono carente, però devo confessare che con il mio cellulare non è semplice inserire lettere accentate, though. Comunque, visto che ci sono, come procede la *chat* 'Bar Sport', is it still alive? If not, what do you think about defining a day or a specific time at which the folks who follow IL can entry and find other folks?

Answer (score 4):

Consideriamo

> il Vaticano ha chiesto di intercedere presso il governo cubano per far cessare la violenza

In questa frase il significato è che il Vaticano ha chiesto a qualcuno che parlasse al governo cubano, ma non si è affatto rivolto direttamente al governo cubano, che implicitamente è considerato connesso con le violenze.

Viceversa

> il Vaticano ha chiesto al governo cubano di intercedere per far cessare la violenza

significa che il Vaticano si è rivolto al governo cubano perché a sua volta faccia pressioni sui responsabili delle violenze. L'inversione “di intercedere al governo cubano” è scorretta.

Il battesimo di Gesù è avvenuto *al* fiume Giordano, più precisamente *nel* fiume. Considererei *il battesimo di Gesù è avvenuto presso il fiume Giordano* un burocratismo, simile a

> la Procura della Repubblica presso il Tribunale di Vattelapesca

anche se, in questo caso, il modo è tradizionale. La Procura è un organo della magistratura distinto dal Tribunale; ogni Tribunale ha una Procura collegata. Non è possibile dire *la Procura della Repubblica al Tribunale di Vattelapesca* e nemmeno *nel*. Gli uffici sono probabilmente nello stesso edificio, ma qui ci si riferisce all'istituzione, non al complesso delle persone che ne fanno parte né alla collocazione fisica. Si userebbe *presso* anche se, per assurdo, gli uffici della Procura fossero a un paio di chilometri dal Tribunale.

In conclusione, *al* e *presso il* non sono intercambiabili: sia *a* sia *presso* indicano stato in luogo, ma *presso* è più indeterminato e significa “vicino”. Considera la differenza fra *abito a Vattelapesca* e *abito presso Vattelapesca*: nel secondo caso sto al massimo in una frazione, non certo in centro.

Answer (score 1):

Io credo che usare  ***al*** fiume Giordano sia corretto, dato che l'autore si riferisce ***al*** luogo dove si e` svolto il battesimo.

```
Domani vado al fiume a pescare.
```

pesco dalla riva non da dentro al fiume, cio` non toglie che vado ***al*** fiume.